# Getting exact string from text file into a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding

I have an encrypted string that is read out of a file. My issue is that it is not coming into a variable like it shows in the file so the resulting decryption is wrong.

Here is the string in the file: `û«hoágè~Àê´•§™Ý`

This code Works:

```
    Dim oldpass As String = "û«hoágè~Àê´•§™Ý"
    MsgBox(mylib.security.LegacyCode.decryptPassword(oldpass))
```

But when trying to do it with via the file:

```
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\mydir\smart\myfile.DAT"
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
    Dim encryptedPw As String = objReader.ReadToEnd
    objReader.Close()
    MsgBox(mylib.security.LegacyCode.decryptPassword(encryptedPw))
```

It is causing issues. While debugging the string in `encryptedPw` doesn't look correct:
[image]

How do I get the string to read into a variable correctly?

Comment: First of all, is the string in the file _definitely_ correct, or could it possibly have been badly encoded into the file by whatever was creating the file?

Comment: It is definitely correct. I opened it and copy and pasted it here: `Dim oldpass As String = "û«hoágè~Àê´•§™Ý"`

Comment: Do you know what encoding the file was saved with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to give the StreamReader a text encoding?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx

As second parameter

```
StreamReader(YourStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

or  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8  or System.Text.Encoding.ASCII ?